# How to check if file exists from url with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, promise

I'm working on a hybrid mobile app based on Ionic -v1 / Cordova and I would like to know the best practices for this.

So far I found an option with the fetch function in the controller function:

```
angular.module('my.controllers')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $q, ws){
    var loadImgLst = ws.getImgList().then(function(response){
        //get image src in a list
        var imgList = response;
        var promisesArray = [];
        for(var i in imgList) {
            var promiseSrc = fetch(imgList[i])
                    .then(function(response) {
                var imgurl = response.url; 
                if(!response.ok)
                {
                    //get fallback img
                    imgurl = "http://mysite/img_default.jpg"; 
                }
                return imgurl;
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
            promisesArray.push(promiseSrc);
        }
        return $q.all(promisesArray);
    });
    loadImgLst.then(function(lstImg)
    {
        $scope.lstImg = lstImg;
    });
});
```

In the html view :

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <div ng-repeat="src in lstImg">
            <img ng-src="{{ src }}">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

When I execute this code on the browser with ionic serve, I still have the error 404 "Not found" in the console but my default image is displayed.

I tried something similar with the XMLHttpRequest() function and try / catch but the result is the same.

Is there a way to avoid (or hide) this error ? An other way to solve this problem ?

Thanks :)

EDIT: I also tried the directive option:

```
.directive('fallback', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('error', function() {
                   element.attr('src', attrs.fallback); 
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and the html view with a file that does not exist in ng-src:

```
<img ng-src="http://mysite/no_img.jpg" fallback="http://mysite/img_default.jpg">
```

I still have this error 404 in the console.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it may be helpful to post a little more of the code for that controller, as it's a little difficult to see exactly what you're doing and therefore resolve your issue! You although you don't want to post absolutely everything it's generally a good idea to show enough code/html so people can run it for themselves.

Comment: The "file" you are trying to check is an image file always? You could do this in html as `ng-src="{{http://mysite/img01.jpg ? http://mysite/img01.jpg : http://mysite/img_default.jpg}}"`

Comment: Yes in this case it will be only images files, if I can get something for other kind of files it can be good also (but for today that will be enough ;) ) Unfortunately I couldn't make your code works for me, I get "http://mysite/img01.jpg" has src in this case.

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML you can do:

```
<img fallback-src="http://mysite/img_default.jpg" ng-src="http://mysite/img.jpg""/>
```

and then in your JS:

```
myApp.directive('fallback', function () {
  var fallback= {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('error', function() {
        angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallback);
      });
    }
   }
   return fallback;
});
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I'm not very familiar with angular and all the possibilities. The directive idea seems to be a good thing, I couldn't make this code works "as it". I will come back after a [good reading](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and a few tests :)

Comment: You should change myApp to angular.module('yourModulName')

Comment: I edited my post with this suggestion. I get the same result. Is it event possible to avoid this error at this level ?